# Why does my antlr grammar seem to properly parse this input?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I've created a small grammar in ANTLR using python (a grammar that can accept either a list of numbers of a list of IDs), and yet when I input a string such as `December 12 1965`, ANTLR will run on the file and show me no errors with the following code (and all of the python code that I'm using is imbedded via the @main):

```python
grammar ParserLang;

options {
    language=Python;
}

@header {
import sys
import antlr3

from ParserLangLexer import ParserLangLexer
}

@main { 
def main(argv, otherArg=None):
    char_stream = antlr3.ANTLRInputStream(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))
    lexer = ParserLangLexer(char_stream)

    tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = ParserLangParser(tokens);

    rule   = parser.entry_rule()
}

program     : idList EOF
            | integerList EOF
            ;

idList      : ID whitespace idList 
            | ID
            ;

integerList : INTEGER whitespace integerList 
            | INTEGER
            ;

whitespace  : (WHITESPACE | COMMENT) +;

ID            : LETTER (DIGIT | LETTER)*;
INTEGER       : (NONZERO_DIGIT DIGIT*) | ZERO ;
WHITESPACE    : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
COMMENT       : ('/*' .* '*/') | ('//' .* '\n') { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;

fragment ZERO            : '0' ;
fragment DIGIT         : '0' .. '9';
fragment NONZERO_DIGIT : '1' .. '9';
fragment LETTER        : 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z';
```

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: When I use ANTLRWorks with the same grammar an input, a NoViableAltException is thrown.  How do I get that error via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce it. When I generate a lexer and parser from your input after fixing the error in the grammar (`rule = parser.entry_rule()` should be: `rule = parser.program()`), and parse the input `"December 12 1965"` (either as input from a file, or as a plain string), I get the following error:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input u'December'
```

Which may seem strange since that could be the start of a `idList`. The fact is, your grammar contains one more error and a small thing that could be improved:

- `WHITESPACE` and `COMMENT` are placed on the `HIDDEN` channel, and are therefor not available in parser rules (at least, not without changing the channel from which the parser reads its tokens...);
- a `COMMENT` at the end of the input, that is, without a `\n` at the end, will not be properly tokenized. Better define a single line comment like this: `'//' ~('\r' | '\n')*`. The trailing line break will be captured by the `WHITESPACE` rule after all.

Because the parser cannot match an `idList` (or a `integerList` for that matter) because of the `whitespace` rule, an error is produced pointing at the very first token (`'December'`).

Here's a grammar that works (as expected):

```
grammar ParserLang;

options {
    language=Python;
}

@header {
import sys
import antlr3

from ParserLangLexer import ParserLangLexer
}

@main { 
def main(argv, otherArg=None):
    lexer = ParserLangLexer(antlr3.ANTLRStringStream('December 12 1965'))
    parser = ParserLangParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer))
    parser.program()
}

program     : idList EOF
            | integerList EOF
            ;

idList      : ID+
            ;

integerList : INTEGER+
            ;

ID          : LETTER (DIGIT | LETTER)*;
INTEGER     : (NONZERO_DIGIT DIGIT*) | ZERO ;
WHITESPACE  : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
COMMENT     : ('/*' .* '*/' | '//' ~('\r' | '\n')*)   { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;

fragment ZERO          : '0' ;
fragment DIGIT         : '0' .. '9';
fragment NONZERO_DIGIT : '1' .. '9';
fragment LETTER        : 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z';
```

Running the parser generated from the grammar above will also produce an error:

```
line 1:9 missing EOF at u'12'
```

but that is expected: after an `idList`, the parser expects the `EOF`, but it encounters `'12'` instead.